# PHP - getting the first sum number only

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are 5 types of prices that have been summed-up in each div using ***MySQL*** query and works perfectly.

Then, I wish to get the sum of those 5 total values by giving them each a `$_SESSION` variable before it sum them all up. It only gets the first price but still sums them up perfectly.

(e.g `$extra_price` is 25 then if i  `$extra_price+$extra_price` the `$total` can get 50)

Lets say if (e.g `$extra_price` is 25 and `$decoprice` is 10 then i sum  `$extra_price+$decoprice` the `$total` only show 25) the 10 has been ignore.

Any idea how to get the sum perfectly ?

Below is my code:

```
<?php 
                $extra_price = $_SESSION['extra_price'];
                $decoprice = $_SESSION['decoprice'];
                $foodprice = $_SESSION['foodprice'];
                $drinksprice =  $_SESSION['drinksprice'];
                $venueprice = $_SESSION['venueprice'];

                $total = $extra_price+$decoprice+$foodprice+$drinksprice+$venueprice;           
                ?>
                        <center><b>Total <?php echo $total ?></b></center>
```

Comment: Put also the code on how you store the values inside those session variables.

Comment: You might want to check that you actually have session variables:  `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: If u `echo` all the variables, u get all the data u want from session ? If not, u should check the register of `$_SESSION`

Comment: @LoganWayne put already , very long

Comment: Why are you even storing them in session variables, since you're just outputting them at the end?

Comment: @CullyLarson i have add up all code

Comment: @JohnPriestakos i have add up all code

Comment: Did you know that it's possible to separate presentation code from business logic? It is. It really is.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 sry i dont understand= =

Answer (score 1):

U shouldnt use this syntax

```
$_SESSION['decoprice'] = $show_pextra['SUM(decoprice)'];
```

Try to name you `SUM(decoprice)` and use it to register the session.

```
select SUM(decoprice) as sum_decoprice from selectdeco where title = '$title'
$_SESSION['decoprice'] = $show_pextra['sum_decoprice '];
```

Comment: the total still same ... no sum up all number

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those extra variables, you can just write it like this:

```
$total = 0;
$keys = array('extra_price', 'decoprice', 'foodprice', 'drinksprice', 'venueprice');
foreach ($keys AS $key)
{
    $total += $_SESSION[$key];
}
```

Obviously, this is irrelevant, just an issue of style. In any case the `+` operator will sum things perfectly for you. That's what it does. It sums things. Perfectly.

But the problem is, nobody knows what's in your $_SESSION. Do you? Why don't you try logging it somewhere or at least doing:

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Then you will see that your session probably doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: i have try your solution but the output still the same

Comment: the `array('extra_price', 'decoprice', 'foodprice', 'drinksprice', 'venueprice');` dirrectly get from other place ? no need declare ?

Comment: Still I don't know what's in your $_SESSION. Could you print_r it and show the result?

Answer (score 0):

Hey first of all you don't need session here. Simple declare total variable at top of your code and replace each session with total variable with plus. and remove extra variables.

Replace

```
$_SESSION['extra_price'] = $show_pextra['SUM(price)'];
```

With

```
$total += $show_pextra['SUM(price)'];
```

Do with all session.

Here is your full code:

```
<?php $total = 0;?>
<tr><!--extra-->
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Extra Item:</td>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_allextra = mysql_query("select * from selectextra where title = '$title'");
        while($show_allextra = mysql_fetch_array($read_allextra))
        {
            ?>
                <b>&diams; <?php echo $show_allextra['extraitem'] ?></b></br>
            <?php
        }

    ?></td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_pextra = mysql_query("select SUM(price) from selectextra where title = '$title'");

        while($show_pextra = mysql_fetch_array($read_pextra))
        {
            ?>
                <center><b>RM <?php echo $show_pextra['SUM(price)'] ?></b></center>
            <?php
            $total += $show_pextra['SUM(price)'];
        }
    ?>

    </td>
</tr>

<tr><!--deco-->
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Decoration :</td>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_alldeco = mysql_query("select * from selectdeco where title = '$title'");
        while($show_alldeco = mysql_fetch_array($read_alldeco))
        {
            ?>
                <b>&diams; <?php echo $show_alldeco['decoitem'] ?></b></br>
            <?php
        }

    ?>

    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
        <?php
        $read_pdeco = mysql_query("select SUM(decoprice) from selectdeco where title = '$title'");

        while($show_pdeco = mysql_fetch_array($read_pdeco))
        {
            ?>
                <center><b>RM <?php echo $show_pdeco['SUM(decoprice)'] ?></b></center>
            <?php
            $total += $show_pextra['SUM(decoprice)'];
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>   

<tr><!--food-->
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Foods :</td>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_allfood = mysql_query("select * from selectfood where title = '$title'");
        while($show_allfood = mysql_fetch_array($read_allfood))
        {
            ?>
                <b>&diams; <?php echo $show_allfood['fooditem'] ?></b></br>
            <?php
        }

    ?>
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_pfood = mysql_query("select SUM(foodprice) from selectfood where title = '$title'");

        while($show_pfood = mysql_fetch_array($read_pfood))
        {
            ?>
                <center><b>RM <?php echo $show_pfood['SUM(foodprice)'] ?></b></center>
            <?php
            $total += $show_pextra['SUM(foodprice)'];
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr><!--drinks-->
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Drinks :</td>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_alldrinks = mysql_query("select * from selectdrinks where title = '$title'");
        while($show_alldrinks = mysql_fetch_array($read_alldrinks))
        {
            ?>
                <b>&diams; <?php echo $show_alldrinks['drinksitem'] ?></b></br>
            <?php
        }

    ?>
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_pdrinks = mysql_query("select SUM(drinksprice) from selectdrinks where title = '$title'");

        while($show_pdrinks = mysql_fetch_array($read_pdrinks))
        {
            ?>
                <center><b>RM <?php echo $show_pdrinks['SUM(drinksprice)'] ?></b></center>
            <?php
            $total += $show_pextra['SUM(drinksprice)'];
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr><!--venue-->
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">&nbsp;&nbsp; Venue :</td>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_allvenue = mysql_query("select * from selectvenue where title = '$title'");
        while($show_allvenue = mysql_fetch_array($read_allvenue))
        {
            ?>
                <b>&diams; <?php echo $show_allvenue['venuename'] ?></b></br>
            <?php
        }

    ?>
    </td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
    <?php
        $read_pvenue = mysql_query("select venueprice from selectvenue where title = '$title'");

        while($show_pvenue = mysql_fetch_array($read_pvenue))
        {
            ?>
                <center><b>RM <?php echo $show_pvenue['venueprice'] ?></b></center>
            <?php
            $total += $show_pextra['SUM(venueprice)'];
        }
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="border:2px solid #000;" colspan="2">
    <center><input type="submit"  class="button" style="width:300px;" value="Pay Now" name="send_payment"/></center></td>
    <td style="width:120px;border:2px solid #000;">
        <center><b>Total <?php echo $total ?></b></center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i try your code the output of total still the same 25, the rest no sum up